# argparse error "takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given"

Tags: python, argparse

I want to implement a parser that changes the parent directory if the user wants to. If that's not necessary, I want the program to use Desktop as the default directory. Now the user gets asked to change the directory every time he runs the program.

I put argparse in if **name** == '**main**' following my supervisor's example. I guess that's causing this error, but I can't figure out what to do about it.

```
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop')
parent_dir = desktop
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--setparentdir',
                        default=desktop,
                        help='sets the parent directory')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.setparentdir:
        parent_dir = input('Enter your directory')
```

```
Enter your directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export_with_parser.py", line 129, in <module>
    download_contents(project_id, project_name)
TypeError: download_contents() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

If the user doesn't enter --setparentdir the program should use the default directory, which is the desktop.

Comment: You are setting a default in `parser.add_argument()` due to which the `if` condition is `True` everytime and therefore it is asking for the input.

Comment: Right. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Don't use default value , this will solve the problem. Do read about `action="store_true"` in `parser.add_argument()`

Comment: Thanks. But I still got the same error.

Comment: The code your traceback references isn't present in the example code you gave. We can't help you solve that problem.

Comment: My bad.... It worked.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you don't want `--setparentdir` to actually set the parent directory.  Rather, you want it to determine whether `input` will be used.  In other words, args.setparentdir should be a boolean.  Booleans are usually controlled with the `store_true` and `store_false` actions.  Since `--setparentdir` isn't directly setting the parent directory, its default should not be `desktop`, it should be `False`, which is the default of `store_true`.

So:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--setparentdir',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='Set the parent directory interactively')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.setparentdir:
        parent_dir = input('Enter your directory')
```